# Errors with Eclipse BIRT report generation

Tags: eclipse, birt

### Context

I am in the midst of upgrading Eclipse BIRT from version `4.8.0` to `4.14.0` for one of our projects that generates reports with the help of Eclipse BIRT. As our team is migrating from Java 8 to Java 17.

### Error stacktrace

When using Eclipse BIRT version `4.14.0`, the report generation fails with the below stacktrace:

```
Jan 04, 2024 5:38:43 PM uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.framework.Logger info
INFO: start:org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.content.impl.ReportContent@1b13dd92
Jan 04, 2024 5:38:45 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DtEScriptExecutor handleJS
WARNING: Fail to execute script in function __bm_FETCH(). Source:
------
"
.. JS code ..
"
-----
A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Encountered code generation error while compiling function "39": generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K limit.
org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: Fail to execute script in function __bm_FETCH(). Source:
------
"
.. JS code ..
"
-----
A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Encountered code generation error while compiling function "39": generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K limit.
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.JSMethodRunner.runScript(JSMethodRunner.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DtEScriptExecutor.handleJS(DtEScriptExecutor.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DataSetScriptExecutor.handleJS(DataSetScriptExecutor.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.handleFetch(ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ScriptDataSetRuntime.fetch(ScriptDataSetRuntime.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedScriptDSQuery$ScriptDSQueryExecutor$CustomDataSet.fetch(PreparedScriptDSQuery.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.OdiAdapter.fetch(OdiAdapter.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.fetch(RowResultSet.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.doNext(RowResultSet.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.next(RowResultSet.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.SimpleResultSet$RowResultSetWithResultSetScope.fetch(SimpleResultSet.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.doNext(RowResultSet.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.next(RowResultSet.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.SimpleResultSet.prepareFirstRow(SimpleResultSet.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.SimpleResultSet.getResultSetIterator(SimpleResultSet.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.CandidateQuery.execute(CandidateQuery.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedScriptDSQuery$ScriptDSQueryExecutor.executeOdiQuery(PreparedScriptDSQuery.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:1074)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.executeQuery(ServiceForQueryResults.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.QueryResultSet.<init>(QueryResultSet.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:69)
    at com.visa.coreconfig.service.rpt.BirtReportGenerationService.generateReport(BirtReportGenerationService.java:97)
    at com.visa.coreconfig.service.ar.ConfigAuditReportService.createAuditReport(ConfigAuditReportService.java:173)
    at com.visa.coreconfig.ar.rest.ConfigAuditReportController.createAuditReport(ConfigAuditReportController.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:254)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:182)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Encountered code generation error while compiling function "39": generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K limit.
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException.wrap(DataException.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.script.BaseScriptEvalUtil.evaluateJSAsExpr(BaseScriptEvalUtil.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.JSMethodRunner.runScript(JSMethodRunner.java:114)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.CoreException: Encountered code generation error while compiling function "39": generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K limit.
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.wrapRhinoException(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateRawScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.api.script.BaseScriptEvalUtil.evaluateJSAsExpr(BaseScriptEvalUtil.java:804)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Encountered code generation error while compiling function "39": generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K limit.
    at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:77)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError(Context.java:998)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.reportClassFileFormatException(Codegen.java:180)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.generateCode(Codegen.java:309)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.compileToClassFile(Codegen.java:166)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.compile(Codegen.java:75)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2559)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1515)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1504)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.getCompiledScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateRawScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:97)
    ... 89 more

Jan 04, 2024 5:38:45 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.ScriptExecutor addException
WARNING: Data Set script method "Fetch" returned null; expected a Boolean value.
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Data Set script method "Fetch" returned null; expected a Boolean value.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.ScriptExecutor.addException(ScriptExecutor.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.ScriptExecutor.addException(ScriptExecutor.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.handleFetch(ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ScriptDataSetRuntime.fetch(ScriptDataSetRuntime.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedScriptDSQuery$ScriptDSQueryExecutor$CustomDataSet.fetch(PreparedScriptDSQuery.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.OdiAdapter.fetch(OdiAdapter.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.fetch(RowResultSet.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.doNext(RowResultSet.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.next(RowResultSet.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.SimpleResultSet$RowResultSetWithResultSetScope.fetch(SimpleResultSet.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.doNext(RowResultSet.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.next(RowResultSet.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.SimpleResultSet.prepareFirstRow(SimpleResultSet.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.SimpleResultSet.getResultSetIterator(SimpleResultSet.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.CandidateQuery.execute(CandidateQuery.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedScriptDSQuery$ScriptDSQueryExecutor.executeOdiQuery(PreparedScriptDSQuery.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:1074)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.executeQuery(ServiceForQueryResults.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.QueryResultSet.<init>(QueryResultSet.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:69)
    at com.visa.coreconfig.service.rpt.BirtReportGenerationService.generateReport(BirtReportGenerationService.java:97)
    at com.visa.coreconfig.service.ar.ConfigAuditReportService.createAuditReport(ConfigAuditReportService.java:173)
    at com.visa.coreconfig.ar.rest.ConfigAuditReportController.createAuditReport(ConfigAuditReportController.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:254)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:182)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: Data Set script method "Fetch" returned null; expected a Boolean value.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.handleFetch(ScriptDataSetScriptExecutor.java:138)
    ... 83 more
```

To summarize the long stacktrace, the main errors are:

- org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.CoreException: Encountered code generation error while compiling function "39": generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K limit.
- WARNING: Data Set script method "Fetch" returned null; expected a Boolean value.
  org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Data Set script method "Fetch" returned null; expected a Boolean value.

### Background info

I have a Java 8 version of this project running with Eclipse BIRT version `4.8.0` & the report can be generated fine.

This project in my local is running on Java 17 with Eclipse BIRT version `4.14.0` but is facing these errors.

Here is the `build.gradle` for the Java 8 version of the project:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.8.RELEASE')
    
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:2.0.2.RELEASE')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.5.37')
    compile('com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot:2.1.0')
    compile('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.0.0')
    
    compile project(':ConfigAuditReportServiceTier')
    
    compile ("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1")  
    compile ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.17.1')
    
    compile('com.ibm.db2:db2jcc_license_cisuz:1.0')
    compile('com.ibm.db2:db2java:1.0')
    compile('com.ibm.db2:jcc:11.5.0.0')
    
    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here is the `build.gradle` for the Java 17 version of the project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.2.0')

    implementation('org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:9.0.78')
    implementation('com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot:3.0.5')
    implementation('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:3.0.3')
    
    implementation ("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.21.1")   
    implementation ('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.21.1')
    
    implementation('com.ibm.db2:db2jcc_license_cisuz:1.0')
    implementation('com.ibm.db2:db2java:1.0')
    implementation('com.ibm.db2:jcc:11.5.0.0')
    
    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

We downloaded the Eclipse BIRT runtime zip (`birt-runtime-4.14.0-202312020807.zip`) from this download link [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/birt/updates/release/4.14.0/downloads/birt-runtime-4.14.0-202312020807.zip), extracted the jars in `birt-runtime-4.14.0-202312020807/ReportEngine` & added them to our project's build path

### Concerns

I don't think the other libraries defined in the `build.gradle` are causing the errors, it's the Eclipse BIRT software.

Comment: It seems that [in Birt a JavaScript function is too large to be converted into Java bytecode](https://github.com/eclipse-birt/birt/blob/3fdaf386991ebb2258ab39d306bbb602875abd4e/data/org.eclipse.birt.data/src/org/eclipse/birt/data/engine/script/JSMethodRunner.java#L123). I don't know much about Birt, but I would assume that if it's not a customized JavaScript function from you, that maybe the function is generated based on the data that in your case leads to exceeding the 64K limit. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: hi @howlger, i am not able to provide the JavaScript code as it contains sensitive business logic but let me see what i can do

Comment: Please see the answer from a BIRT developer below.

Comment: hi @howlger, i have shared the JS code in the JSFiddle link updated in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 64k limit is a limitation of the Rhino Javascript engine BIRT is using.
Fixing it is outside the scope of BIRT.

As said in a comment, you should provide a minimal reproducible example.

We are using scripting in BIRT 4.14 heavily, and it just works.

It is well possible that your method compiled to eg 61 kb bytecode with Java 8 and now with Java 17 the byte code is slightly bigger, eg. 64.1 kb.

You should refactor your JS code.

Comment: hi @hvb, thank you for your response, i have shared the JS function causing the Exception in the JSFiddle link updated in my question. looking at the JS function, i'm not quite sure how else i could refactor it. could you share ways a JS function could be refactored, any examples/guides would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: @waffledood With the (nested) function `function newRowProperty(dfltProperty, recordProperty) { return dfltProperty != null && recordProperty == dfltProperty ? "(" + recordProperty + ")" : recordProperty; }` you can shorten many lines of your JS code (e.g. `row.tcr5AcqrIndC = newRowProperty(dflt.getTcr5AcqrInd(), record.getTcr5AcqrInd());`).

Comment: thank you @howlger, that is very helpful -- so a starting point is to remove any code duplication, anything else?

Comment: @waffledood Instead of the nested function, you can iterate directly over the property names: `for (rowProperty of ['mailingAddr', ... ]) { var dfltProperty =  dflt['get' + rowProperty.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + rowProperty.substring(1)](); var recordProperty = ...; row[rowProperty] = ... }`.

Comment: @howlger hi howlger, you can open up another answer & i will accept it, the suggestions you gave work. No exceptions during the report generation now.

Comment: @waffledood Thanks, but from my side, it was just guessing and some help in your specific case. The general answer, which is helpful for others, has already been given by hvb, who is by the way one of those who maintain and keep the BIRT project alive.

Comment: hi hvb & howlger, i opened up a new question on Eclipse BIRT, with regards to the JavaScript to Java bytecode compilation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77790824/eclipse-birt-java-bytecode-compilation-done-at-compile-time-or-runtime), if you guys have any inputs/ideas, appreciate your responses!