# Eclipse BIRT - Java bytecode compilation done at compile time or runtime?

Tags: eclipse, birt

Does the JavaScript to Java bytecode compilation happen at runtime? It seems to be so.

Because when I build the project with `gradlew build`, I do not see any errors or warnings related to Eclipse BIRT.

I only got the following error when I called a REST endpoint to generate a report:

```
-----
A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Encountered code generation error while compiling function "39": generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K limit.
org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: Fail to execute script in function __bm_FETCH(). Source:
------
```

Is it possible to know beforehand which scripts are exceeding the 64K limit? Because there are quite a lot of scripts (20+) to manually test for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BIRT reports are just XML files.
The Javascript is stored as text inside them (or in separate *.js files).
At runtime, the Rhino Javascript engine (a Javascript implementation written in Java) compiles the scripts to Java bytecode.
Note that you can store utility code which you need in several reports in *.js files (see the ressources property tab for the report properties).

BTW because BIRT only supports (most of) the old ECMAScript 5 standard, and because JS itself is not well-suited for complex code (in comparison to e.g. Typescript), I'd recommend to avoid large scripts if possible.

Manually testing if 20-30 script in reports are working shouldn't take long.
Creating a test programs that tries to check this automatically is much more work. I'd recommend automating this only if you expect to switch BIRT and Java releases on a regular base. But OTOH you can just create a test script that runs all these reports and tests if they work as expected.

Comment: hi @hvb, thanks for your response! we set up each script for each “entity“ in our application, so to trigger each script, i need to manually set up some test data for each “entity“. my testing process now is to first create the test data, then make a POST request to the endpoint that generates the report. the automated test script you suggested -- would it involve automating my testing process? or is there some other automation that BIRT supports, thanks!